# Prove inequality between two $\sup$s in $\mathbb{C}$ and in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers, real-numbers, supremum-and-infimum

Consider $A=\{z \in \mathbb{C}: |z|<1\}$ and $B=\{x \in \mathbb{R}: |x|<1\}$ and $N \in \mathbb{N}$. How can I prove the following inequality?

$$\sup_{z \in A} \frac{|z^{N}|}{|1-z|}\geq \sup_{x \in B}\frac{|x^{N}|}{|1-x|}$$

---

I tried using $|1-z|\geq |1-|z||$ but it doesn't seem the proper way to do it.

Comment: $B \subset A$, this is all you need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supremum on the left side is taken over a bigger set (since $B \subset A$). Thus, the supremum on the left is greater.